# How to sync Google Cloud Storage bucket with local folder for offline usage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, rsync

I need to sync (not mirror) files between a local disk and a cloud bucket. I can think of something like the Google Drive app, that works also in offline mode (and when the local PC goes online it automatically syncs data). This is useful for the app I'm going to develop, because of offline usage.

I dig a lot into the documentation but I didn't find any useful resource.

I can use `gcloud rsync` in combination with a Cloud Function to listen to cloud bucket events.
And a custom, local, trigger for events on the local hard disk (let's assume I'm developing a Node.JS local app).
But then I've to handle edge situations like: offline, concurrent operations, very long transfers, permissions, etc.

I don't want to re-invent the wheel and I think this is a common pattern, like the previously mentioned GDrive app.
Also, Firestore Native Mode does implement something really close to, although it's related to documents and not files.

Does Google Cloud Platform and/or Firebase allow the synchronization of local folder with cloud bucket with ease?
What do you think about my approach?

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, these functions are implemented in Google Drive / One, and for these products, this is the main intention  "to be a cloud drive" (basically all the time it is in sync with your local devices).

On the other hand, Google Cloud Storage is a service with a different approach, this is an object-based storage and was designed as part of the Cloud architecture to interact with cloud services (always online services), at this time Google does not offer a similar software client (as Google Drive does) for syncing local and cloud folders.

I found this [third party software](http://www.risefly.com/fsedwld.htm) (not supported by Google) that allows syncing between local folders and cloud storage

Also I reviewed the pricing for Google One and cloud storage and Google One is significantly cheaper, for example.

```
2 TB / month G ONE: $ 10 USD
2TB / month G storage: $ 40 USD
```

Based on this, you should also add the price of additional services, for example.

- pubsub service
- cloud function service
- outgoing network traffic

Your approach sounds good (it takes a lot of effort but it's okay) but unfortunately you are trying to use a service in an off-design scenario.

If you want to save code in the cloud, you can use [Google Cloud Repositories](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories) which basically works like Github, but has the advantage of being easily integrated with CI/CD services like [Google Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build)